# VBA if A = B and C= Text

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking on stackoverflow but could not get an definitive answer to my little problem. I am fairly new to coding and am still dealing with syntax sometimes.

Right now I have a little loop reading an array, inside the loop it checks for an if statement. I have been checking the loop which works fine, and the array as well. The if statement works until im starting to use "isText".

After searching a bit I noticed "isText" is not a function, is there something equivalent?

Right now my if statement goes as follows: `IF A = B and C` (Contains ANY value at all) `then Write something somewhere in a cell`

Right now the code I am using is:

```
Sub KnopKlik()

Dim Soorten(10)
Dim Teller As Integer
Dim Column1 As String
Column1 = Sheets(2).Range("C1").Value

MsgBox (Column1)
Sheets(1).Select
Range("E2").Select

For Teller = 0 To 10
    Soorten(Teller) = ActiveCell.Offset(Teller).Value

Next Teller


For Teller = 0 To 10

If Sheets(2).Range("B9") = Soorten(Teller) And Application.IsText(Column1) Then

    MsgBox ("Check")
    Sheets(2).Range("E9").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(Teller, 3)
    Sheets(2).Select
    Range("B9").Select

    Teller = 10
    Else
End If


Next Teller

End Sub
```

Right now the last part of the if statement is the problem

```
And Application.IsText(Column1) Then
```

EDIT**

This is how I solved it now. Basically whenever there is ANYTHING at all in that cell it will pass through.

```
If Sheets(2).Range("B9") = Soorten(Teller) Then
'Als B9 Gelijk is aan (database) DAN!>>>
    If Not Column1 = "" Then
    Sheets(2).Range("E9").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(Teller, 3)
    End If
    Else
End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Application.IsText` should work - it should do the same thing as `ISTEXT` in Excel.  What is happening when you use it?  (Of course, `ISTEXT` only tests for text, not for numbers, etc, so it doesn't really seem you want to use that - it sounds like you want to use the VBA `Not IsEmpty(Collum1)` but I'm still intrigued as to why you say there is no `IsText` function.)

Comment: Apparently it does work yeah, i think cause of the amount of testing and i have been trying to get it right i must have overlooked that it actually does work.... Before using "And Application.IsText(Collum1) Then" i had Application. removed and that gave me a error sub is not diffined. The small problem i run up with using it this way. Is that a empty cell also gets  seen as a "Text". So ill prob have to use Vityata his way of putting it in.

Comment: Or just use `... And Not IsEmpty(Collum1) Then` where `IsEmpty` is the built-in VBA function to test for an empty cell.  It depends on whether you want a cell containing the formula `=""` to be treated as "anything at all in that cell" (`IsEmpty` would say that **is** anything) or whether you want that formula to be treated as **not** being anything (in which case Vityata's answer would be the better approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
If Sheets(2).Range("B9") = Soorten(Teller) And Len(Trim(Column1)) > 0 Then
```

The len will return the length of the string. The Trim will remove the empty spaces from left and right, thus if it is an empty string it will be true.